# Paypal payment result--check who paid for what

Tags: php, paypal, web, paypal-ipn

In general, i'am looking for a way to determine "who paid for what" when I get a Paypal payment.

I'm developing a e-commerce website and am trying paypal as the payment method. However, i'm confused about how to associate the response (IPN message from paypal, which i currently intend to rely on solely) with a specific transaction happening on my site.

What i expected was that maybe when customer click on my paypal button to pay, i could tell paypal "hi, this is a transaction with id 1234"; then paypal could tell me "transaction 1234 is completed\canceled". However, i didn't find some "stamp" that i can put on a transaction so that i can know who paid for what. The txn_id variable seem to be close to what i expected, but as i understand now, it's generated by paypal instead of assigned by me.

I also thought about doing some tricks on the redirect_url I send to paypal. May be I could generate a url for each transaction, send that url as a code to paypal; so that when someone requests that url I know the transaction is paid for as only paypal and i know the existence of that url. However, i'm not sure about the security about this method, and think there may be other ways.

Thanks in advance for any idea or direction!

Comment: I do this using the `custom` variable - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH00W2J. I put the transaction number as the custom -> `custom='invoice1234'`, and then verify it when it is returned in the ipn.

Comment: @Sean, how do you put the custom variable, is is put at the button creation time, or dynamically when the user clicks on the buy now button? I think it should be the latter. If this is the case, how do you dynamically append the custom transaction number to each user click?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, that work well with `custom` and `invoice` they send them back to the `notify_url` link.

Comment: Where to add custom property, I checked `Add advanced variables` at step 3 of the buy now button creation process, but no matter what variable I put there, the generated html does not change. Yes I am confused I think it makes no sense to put a static custom value at button creation process, it should be dynamically generated each time a user clicks on the buy button. Can you instruct me how to add the custom variable? Thanks.

Comment: I add them in PHP: <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="xxxx">

Comment: Thanks, @Croises. That makes sense to me. I will go and do some test according to your instruction and I will come back here to give the bounty if it works or with further questions if it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks, @Croises! Works like a charm! Sorry, it says I can only award the bounty in 21 hours. I will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use paypal button like this- Just replace appropriate values and update

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="90">
```

value dynamically using js. Then you can access custom field in you **notify_url**

```
<div class="paypal-button-loader-script-tag">
    <form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal-button" target="_top">
        <div class="hide" id="errorBox"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="button" value="buynow data-quantity=">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Moneyfan">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="yourwebsite.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="90">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yourwebsite.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://yourwebsite.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www.sandbox">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_buynow data-quantity=">
        <button type="submit" class="paypal-button large">undefined</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SatishShinde for the very comprehensive code. That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm sorry I promised to give the bounty to Croises. I appreciate your code.